# How to make auto resizing header view in tableview swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I just dropped a view inside my table view, the view is containing images and labels. But Label content is dynamic and don't wanna crop it instead I want to increase the height of the view as per need. But header view also doesn't accept constraints. So would I achieve? The problem is occurring for the label which is placed above the find friends button.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TableView header height is not automatically refreshed and you must recalculate the height by your own each time its content changes. Heigh recalculation and tableview header refresh can be done in 'viewDidLayoutSubviews' method.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        guard let headerView = tableView.tableHeaderView else {
            return
        }
        let size = headerView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize)

        if headerView.frame.size.height != size.height {
            headerView.frame.size.height = size.height
            tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
            // This only seems to be necessary on iOS 9.
            tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
```

The answer and code snipet are brief summary of "[Variable Height Table View Header](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/variable-height-table-view-header/)" post, accessible at usyourloaf

Comment: After applying the above code my tableview header overlapped the tableView

Answer (score -1):

you need to estimate label height with text and plus with image/ button height to calculate total height of header view

```
func estimatedLabelHeight(text: String, width: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {

    let size = CGSize(width: width, height: 1000)

    let options = NSStringDrawingOptions.usesFontLeading.union(.usesLineFragmentOrigin)

    let attributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: font]

    let rectangleHeight = String(text).boundingRect(with: size, options: options, attributes: attributes, context: nil).height

    return rectangleHeight
}
```

here is the method to estimate header height:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return label size + other size
}
```

or you can use auto layout to avoid estimate height:

- set label numberOfLines = 0
- set vertical padding constraint between each cell in vertical direction
- return ***UITableView.automaticDimension*** in

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
   return UITableView.automaticDimension
}
```

Comment: but where would I use this function

Comment: you can use autolayout and let system estimate height too